# An unusual pattern associated with perfect number

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, perfect-numbers

The pattern is that if you take a perfect number and place **5** at its unit digit. Then you have to square that number after squaring it the digits of the obtained number can be rearranged into two or more squares.

For example : 6 is the first perfect number. Putting 5 at the end gives us **65**

Then. $65^2 = 4225$

Which can be represented as **4 = $2^2$** and **225 = $15^2$** 
I cross checked this result till fifth perfect number. But I want to prove this and but I can't .

Comment: $4965^2 = 24651225$ doesn't seem to work? There are no perfect squares for any string of numbers that use the first $2$ there (except the full number, of course). Some are close, but not exactly.

Comment: There are 3 ways to do so for this number as $4 = 2^2 ; 256 = 16^2 ; 1225 = 35^2$

Comment: $4 = 2^2 ; 625 = 25^2 ; 1225 = 35^2$

Comment: Oh, you're rearranging the digits. That's going to be a tough one to prove.

Comment: Well you can counter but that will be tough too. But not as compared to the prove.

Comment: Have you established that this observation holds only for perfect numbers? If it holds for other numbers as well, then there is no basis for framing this as a question about perfect numbers. For what numbers does  the observation fail to hold?

Comment: Yes there are many numbers that follow this pattern solve prime numbers such as 7 and 13. One composite number 14.

Comment: And some number ending in 5 also such as 35 and 475 and I can find such more configuration but the fact is not all prime number follow this and not all composite numbers or number ending in $five$ but perfect number do this I believe that every perfect number will follow this.